# i want to align my elements so that they start in the same place (vertically)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to do some CSS and I have 4 items on a line.
I would like to align my 2 "sous-jacent de référence" but I don't know how can I do it.
I tried to use `position: relative` but it didn't work
[image]

there is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.left {
  padding-left: 2%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.left2 {
  padding-left: 2%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.left3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  position: absolute;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.right2 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="title">
    <h2>Formulaire</h2>

  </div>

  <div class="left">
    typologie du produit
  </div>
  <div class="left2">
    <input type="text" id="typologie" name="typologie" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> </div>
  <div class="right">
    Sous-jacent de référence
  </div>
  <div class="left2">
    <input type="text" id="Sous-jacent" name="Sous-jacent" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> </div>

  <div class="left">
    Nom du produit


  </div>
  <div class="left2">
    <input type="text" id="typologie" name="typologi2" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> </div>

  <div class="right">
    Sous-jacent de référence
  </div>
  <div class="left2">
    <input type="text" id="Sous-jacent" name="Sous-jacent2" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> </div>



</body>

</html>
```

I want to say to my algorithm: "my 3 and div begins at x%"

I tried a lot of things (it works when I use `float: right` but it's quite confusing)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you adjust HTML code, or it's should be done only by CSS?

Comment: yes i can adjust Html like Css

Comment: CSS-Grid or Flexbox. **Definitely** not using `float`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using **flex** to align your items in your layout.
Create wrappers to each cell (title and input) you have and wrap all cells to one parent wrapper.
In this case you can control each cell separately and create flexible grid you want.

Moreover, you can simplify your cells, please check first two rows of Code Snippet.
Is it works for you?

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: white;
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(50% - .5rem);
  column-gap: 1rem;
}


/* old code */


/*.left {
  padding-left: 2%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.left2 {
  padding-left: 2%;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.left3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
  position: absolute;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.right2 {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 30%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 2%;
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="title">
    <h2>Formulaire</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="text">
        typologie du produit
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="typologie" name="typologie" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10">
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="text">
        Sous-jacent de référence
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="Sous-jacent" name="Sous-jacent" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10">
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="left">
        typologie du produit
      </div>
      <div class="left2">
        <input type="text" id="typologie" name="typologie" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> </div>

    </div>

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="right">
        Sous-jacent de référence
      </div>
      <div class="left2">
        <input type="text" id="Sous-jacent" name="Sous-jacent" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="left">
        Nom du produit


      </div>
      <div class="left2">
        <input type="text" id="typologie" name="typologi2" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="right">
        Sous-jacent de référence
      </div>
      <div class="left2">
        <input type="text" id="Sous-jacent" name="Sous-jacent2" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it works! i am checking your code

Comment: Solutions without explanation deem instant downvote.

Comment: @カメロン I've added some comments to my answer a bit later)

Answer (score 2):

Remove all `floats` and `padding` associated with the `left` and `right` divs. Then nest each side into `wrappers` and use flexbox. Then you can space them by using `gap`. Lastly, you can restrict the width of each div's text so that the spacing is all the same and the inputs stack right on top of each other, you can do that by setting a `min-width`

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 40px;
}

.left,
.right {
  min-width: 170px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="title">
         <h2>Formulaire</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="left">
            typologie du produit
         </div>
         <div class="left2">
            <input type="text" id="typologie" name="typologie" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> 
         </div>
         <div class="right">
            Sous-jacent de référence
         </div>
         <div class="left2">
            <input type="text" id="Sous-jacent" name="Sous-jacent" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> 
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="left">
            Nom du produit
         </div>
         <div class="left2">
            <input type="text" id="typologie" name="typologi2" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> 
         </div>
         <div class="right">
            Sous-jacent de référence
         </div>
         <div class="left2">
            <input type="text" id="Sous-jacent" name="Sous-jacent2" required minlength="2" maxlength="50" size="10"> 
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works too, thanks! I am checking your solution and the difference between my "old" code